# Opening Large CSV files?

Tags: sql-server, csv, large-files

I have a file that I need to import to a MS-SQL Database but I am not able to open it because my computer only has 4 Gigs of RAM.. I normally use a CSV splitter to make large files smaller but it is not working for this file (155 Gigs)

Can anyone tell me a way to deal with this file for importing into the database (besides buying a new computer with better hardware)

Thank you

Comment: Open the file and read one line at a time and build DB from there

Comment: The computer is having problems opening the file.. Can you send sample script you recommend so I can test it?

Answer (score 3):

In this case I would suggest to use either `SSIS` (if possible) or simpler a small `PowerShell` script. You can find working scripts [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Import-Large-CSVs-into-SQL-216223d9) and [here](https://blog.netnerds.net/2015/01/powershell-high-performance-techniques-for-importing-csv-to-sql-server/).

Both `PowerShell` scripts will iterate over a few rows and import them before they unload them from the memory and take the next ones. In the last link, you can just specify the variable $batchsize which will load the data in defined blocks.

Comment: Thank you for the scripts, I will try then tonight when I get home and let you know the results

Answer (score 0):

A streaming CSV splitter would be a lot more efficient because it processes the file in chunks (of bytes) instead of trying load the entire file into memory before processing it.  node-csv does that but you will need to install node.js in order to use it.

https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-csv

https://nodejs.org/

Answer (score 0):

If your file is just simple comma separated values (doesn't have columns that have commas and therefore double quotes around them), you can also use [BCP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to load the data. It's quite simple to use if the file doesn't have anything special in it.

For more complex cases SSIS is probably the better solution. When importing something this big, make sure you set -b option so that the whole file isn't a one batch and depending on your file contents you want to use -c (ascii) or -w (unicode)